# Android accessibility automatic scanning does not scan custom OSK

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility, accessibility-api

I am currently working on a on screen keyboard designed for differently abled users. Because of the use case, there are quite a few custom touch events implementation.

While it is working as expected in touch mode, during a testing session using the automatic scanning feature using a bluetooth switch, the system completely ignores the custom OSK. I tried adding focusable, focusableInTouchMode on the root keyboard view, but still the keyboard view is getting ignored.

Now my question is, is there a rule or some kind of guideline to follow to get the automatic scanning working ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Switch Access offers the user the ability to perform actions. You'll need to expose actions like action_click to the accessibility API.

Keyboards often draw their UI on the screen directly, and thus need to use ExploreByTouchHelper to expose a virtual view hierarchy to accessibility.

These are general comments since I don't know what approach you're taking to build your UI.

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you for your comment. Currently the keyboard ui is built using a derivation of the KeyboardView class. It makes sense that it is not working because we are not handling clicks and long clicks conventionally. We instead have an option for the user to choose how long they want to hold the key, and also different other touch based customizations. 

I will do more research on ExploreByTouchHelper as this is the first time I am hearing about it.  Thanks again!